# How do I change the spacing between columns in c3.js?

Tags: css, padding, c3.js

For example, my current chart looks like this [image: bar chart]

How do I make them look like this ?

[image]

Comment: Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/SpinWhatXXX/pen/wgMzEY?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ratio setting:

```
bar.width.ratio = 0.8
```

or

```
bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.8
    }
}
```

Comment: That only made my bars thinner

Comment: maybe include some actual code in your question? that's the setting, my friend

Comment: define your data like so instead: ['data1',60, 30, 30]